# How should I give dynamic styles to class?

Tags: html, angular, sass

I am doing an angular project. Where do I need to have a dynamic class set to HTML element problem is I am not able to set styles correctly for dynamic class. I tried the following resources to correct my CSS

https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

https://dev.to/sarah_chima/nesting-in-sass-bme

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="header-style" 
[ngClass]="dynamic_class" fxFill>
     <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
          <mat-icon svgIcon="{{ icon_path }}" aria-label=""></mat-icon>
     </div>
</div>

<!-- following is different div in same html -->

<div fxLayout="row" class="footer-style" 
[ngClass]="dynamic_class" fxFill>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="{{ icon_path }}" aria-label=""></mat-icon>
      </div>
</div>
```

so I want to write CSS for `dynamic_class` which is used in two different `div` and will be having different styles like below

```
dynamic_class {    //this is for header i.e. 1st div
   padding: 12px;
}

dynamic_class {    //this is for footer i.e. 2nd div
   padding: 12px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. But you can restrict which class is applied by the parent element:

```
.header-style dynamic_class {    //this is for header i.e. 1st div
padding: 12px;
}

.footer-style dynamic_class {    //this is for footer i.e. 2nd div
padding: 12px 8px;
}
```

Comment: dynamic_class seems to be a property of type string not a string itself (this is why it's called "dynamic" ;) )... So I don't think this is what @AviatorX want. I agree with you that the question isn't so clear.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about css or scss but, is `header-style` parent of `dynamic_class` ?

Answer (score 0):

> so I want to write css for dynamic_class which is used in two different div and will be having different styles

So put that in the scss.

```
.header-style .dynamic_class {   
   padding: 12px;
}

.footer-style .dynamic_class { 
   padding: 12px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write **[ngClass]="'dynamic_class'"** instead of [ngClass]="dynamic_class" and also take a look at css

**CSS**

```
.header-style.dynamic_class {
padding: 12px;
}

.footer-style.dynamic_class {
padding: 12px 8px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="header-style" 
 [ngClass]="'dynamic_class'" fxFill>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
               dsfaSfdf
        </div>
</div>

<!-- following is different div in same html -->


<div fxLayout="row" class="footer-style"
 [ngClass]="'dynamic_class'" fxFill>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                dsfsfsd
        </div>
</div>
```